# How do I pass additional parameters to transformClassesWithDexForDebug using Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dex

I have an Android application that is failing to compile on the `transformClassesWithDexForDebug` step. I need to pass in some custom arguments to the compiler to get past this step (specifically, `--core-library` because I am mocking some missing javax libraries expected by an apache commons lib that is being used). There is some advice in the [Google Android issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79280) about how to do this:

```
project.tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex) {
    additionalParameters=['--core-library']
}
```

However it does not have any effect on the `transformClassesWithDexForDebug` step - the arguments are not passed and the step always fails.

How can I pass additional parameters to javac in the `transformClassesWithDexForDebug` step with gradle?

Comment: Have you tried to create custom task, disable the task inside your task, and run it beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this functionality [was removed in v1.5.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/adt-dev/uGogKKuuHi8), although Xavier mentioned that they want to fix that.

In the meantime you can revert to an older version of Gradle plugin.